# Put ping parameters as default ping command

Tags: linux, ping

I have some problems with ping. As root user i can't ping if i don't put from which interface to go. So if i "ping google.com" it wont ping. But if i ping like " ping -I eth0 " will ping. (Ok is not route problems, it's other parameters problems too ). So I work with MONIT where i like to tell him, that if there is no ping restart the tunnel or what ever. So i change the /root/.bashrc file and add the ping parameters and when i log in to a machine i have successful ping without specifying the parameters. 
BUT if i ping like "/bin/ping google.com" again same problem it does not take the parameters from .bashrc. But MONIT does not take bashrc he just execute from bin ( looking from the log files

```
    localhost sudo:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/monit.d ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/ping 192.168.1.1
```

Also if i log in with different user same situation the user wont ping at all. If im login as root and use the ping ( but put the .bashrc parameters fro ping ) everything works perfect.

So i would like to change this default ping with this parameters, so no meter how i execute and with what user, it will use with the parameters that ill put. Is there a way to do this ?

```
###############################################################################
## Monit control file
###############################################################################
##
## Comments begin with a '#' and extend through the end of the line. Keywords
## are case insensitive. All path's MUST BE FULLY QUALIFIED, starting with '/'.
##
## Below you will find examples of some frequently used statements. For 
## information about the control file and a complete list of statements and 
## options, please have a look in the Monit manual.
##
##
###############################################################################
## Global section
###############################################################################
##
## Start Monit in the background (run as a daemon):
#
# set daemon  120           # check services at 2-minute intervals
#     with start delay 240  # optional: delay the first check by 4-minutes (by 
#                           # default Monit check immediately after Monit start)
#
#
## Set syslog logging with the 'daemon' facility. If the FACILITY option is
## omitted, Monit will use 'user' facility by default. If you want to log to 
## a standalone log file instead, specify the full path to the log file
#
# set logfile syslog facility log_daemon                       
#
#
### Set the location of the Monit id file which stores the unique id for the
### Monit instance. The id is generated and stored on first Monit start. By 
### default the file is placed in $HOME/.monit.id.
#
# set idfile /var/.monit.id
#
### Set the location of the Monit state file which saves monitoring states
### on each cycle. By default the file is placed in $HOME/.monit.state. If
### the state file is stored on a persistent filesystem, Monit will recover
### the monitoring state across reboots. If it is on temporary filesystem, the
### state will be lost on reboot which may be convenient in some situations.
#
# set statefile /var/.monit.state
#
## Set the list of mail servers for alert delivery. Multiple servers may be 
## specified using a comma separator. By default Monit uses port 25 - it is
## possible to override this with the PORT option.
#
# set mailserver mail.bar.baz,               # primary mailserver
#                backup.bar.baz port 10025,  # backup mailserver on port 10025
#                localhost                   # fallback relay
#
#
## By default Monit will drop alert events if no mail servers are available. 
## If you want to keep the alerts for later delivery retry, you can use the 
## EVENTQUEUE statement. The base directory where undelivered alerts will be 
## stored is specified by the BASEDIR option. You can limit the maximal queue
## size using the SLOTS option (if omitted, the queue is limited by space 
## available in the back end filesystem).
#
# set eventqueue
#     basedir /var/monit  # set the base directory where events will be stored
#     slots 100           # optionally limit the queue size
#
#
## Send status and events to M/Monit (for more informations about M/Monit 
## see http://mmonit.com/).
#
# set mmonit http://monit:monit@192.168.1.10:8080/collector
#
#
## Monit by default uses the following alert mail format:
##
## --8<--
## From: monit@$HOST                         # sender
## Subject: monit alert --  $EVENT $SERVICE  # subject
##
## $EVENT Service $SERVICE                   #
##                                           #
##  Date:        $DATE                   #
##  Action:      $ACTION                 #
##  Host:        $HOST                   # body
##  Description: $DESCRIPTION            #
##                                           #
## Your faithful employee,                   #
## Monit                                     #
## --8<--
##
## You can override this message format or parts of it, such as subject
## or sender using the MAIL-FORMAT statement. Macros such as $DATE, etc.
## are expanded at runtime. For example, to override the sender, use:
#
# set mail-format { from: monit@foo.bar }
#
#
## You can set alert recipients whom will receive alerts if/when a 
## service defined in this file has errors. Alerts may be restricted on 
## events by using a filter as in the second example below. 
#
# set alert sysadm@foo.bar                       # receive all alerts
# set alert manager@foo.bar only on { timeout }  # receive just service-
#                                                # timeout alert
#
#
## Monit has an embedded web server which can be used to view status of 
## services monitored and manage services from a web interface. See the
## Monit Wiki if you want to enable SSL for the web server. 
#
set httpd port 2812 and
    use address x.x.x.x.x  # only accept connection from localhost
    allow 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0        # allow localhost to connect to the server and
    allow admin:password    # require user 'admin' with password 'monit'
    allow @monit           # allow users of group 'monit' to connect (rw)
    allow @users readonly  # allow users of group 'users' to connect readonly

#
###############################################################################
## Services
###############################################################################
##
## Check general system resources such as load average, cpu and memory
## usage. Each test specifies a resource, conditions and the action to be
## performed should a test fail.
#
#  check system myhost.mydomain.tld
#    if loadavg (1min) > 4 then alert
#    if loadavg (5min) > 2 then alert
#    if memory usage > 75% then alert
#    if cpu usage (user) > 70% then alert
#    if cpu usage (system) > 30% then alert
#    if cpu usage (wait) > 20% then alert
#
#    
## Check a file for existence, checksum, permissions, uid and gid. In addition
## to alert recipients in the global section, customized alert can be sent to 
## additional recipients by specifying a local alert handler. The service may 
## be grouped using the GROUP option. More than one group can be specified by
## repeating the 'group name' statement.
#    
#  check file apache_bin with path /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd
#    if failed checksum and 
#       expect the sum 8f7f419955cefa0b33a2ba316cba3659 then unmonitor
#    if failed permission 755 then unmonitor
#    if failed uid root then unmonitor
#    if failed gid root then unmonitor
#    alert security@foo.bar on {
#           checksum, permission, uid, gid, unmonitor
#        } with the mail-format { subject: Alarm! }
#    group server
#
#    
## Check that a process is running, in this case Apache, and that it respond
## to HTTP and HTTPS requests. Check its resource usage such as cpu and memory,
## and number of children. If the process is not running, Monit will restart 
## it by default. In case the service is restarted very often and the 
## problem remains, it is possible to disable monitoring using the TIMEOUT
## statement. This service depends on another service (apache_bin) which
## is defined above.
#    
#  check process apache with pidfile /usr/local/apache/logs/httpd.pid
#    start program = "/etc/init.d/httpd start" with timeout 60 seconds
#    stop program  = "/etc/init.d/httpd stop"
#    if cpu > 60% for 2 cycles then alert
#    if cpu > 80% for 5 cycles then restart
#    if totalmem > 200.0 MB for 5 cycles then restart
#    if children > 250 then restart
#    if loadavg(5min) greater than 10 for 8 cycles then stop
#    if failed host www.tildeslash.com port 80 protocol http
#       and request "/somefile.html"
#       then restart
#    if failed port 443 type tcpssl protocol http
#       with timeout 15 seconds
#       then restart
#    if 3 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
#    depends on apache_bin
#    group server
#    
#    
## Check filesystem permissions, uid, gid, space and inode usage. Other services,
## such as databases, may depend on this resource and an automatically graceful
## stop may be cascaded to them before the filesystem will become full and data
## lost.
#
#  check filesystem datafs with path /dev/sdb1
#    start program  = "/bin/mount /data"
#    stop program  = "/bin/umount /data"
#    if failed permission 660 then unmonitor
#    if failed uid root then unmonitor
#    if failed gid disk then unmonitor
#    if space usage > 80% for 5 times within 15 cycles then alert
#    if space usage > 99% then stop
#    if inode usage > 30000 then alert
#    if inode usage > 99% then stop
#    group server
#
#
## Check a file's timestamp. In this example, we test if a file is older 
## than 15 minutes and assume something is wrong if its not updated. Also,
## if the file size exceed a given limit, execute a script
#
#  check file database with path /data/mydatabase.db
#    if failed permission 700 then alert
#    if failed uid data then alert
#    if failed gid data then alert
#    if timestamp > 15 minutes then alert
#    if size > 100 MB then exec "/my/cleanup/script" as uid dba and gid dba
#
#
## Check directory permission, uid and gid.  An event is triggered if the 
## directory does not belong to the user with uid 0 and gid 0.  In addition, 
## the permissions have to match the octal description of 755 (see chmod(1)).
#
#  check directory bin with path /bin
#    if failed permission 755 then unmonitor
#    if failed uid 0 then unmonitor
#    if failed gid 0 then unmonitor
#
#
## Check a remote host availability by issuing a ping test and check the 
## content of a response from a web server. Up to three pings are sent and 
## connection to a port and an application level network check is performed.
#
#  check host myserver with address 192.168.1.1
#    if failed icmp type echo count 3 with timeout 3 seconds then alert
#    if failed port 3306 protocol mysql with timeout 15 seconds then alert
#    if failed url http://user:password@www.foo.bar:8080/?querystring
#       and content == 'action="j_security_check"'
#       then alert
#
#
###############################################################################
## Includes
###############################################################################
##
## It is possible to include additional configuration parts from other files or
## directories.
#
#  include /etc/monit.d/*
#
#

# set daemon mode timeout to 1 minute
set daemon 60
# Include all files from /etc/monit.d/
include /etc/monit.d/*
```

Kind regards

Comment: You have your password showing in the config file you pasted. You probably want to change that on your live system.

Comment: heheeh yee i change it but this is still testing environment and no public ip is published. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: What is wrong with your routing? Can you show us the output of `ip route`?

Comment: This is Openswan hosted on Hyper-V, and the tunnels are established but there is no route in the routing table. There is in ip xfrm policy. So the problem lies in Hyper-V there is no promiscuous mode option. That is way in ip xfrm policy there is a route but not in ip route. I have test this on many different Linux on Hyper-V. Same problem. So when i ping with small packets and give the output of the interface i have reply. Because one tunnel always going down i like to put monit with ping and if it fails to restart the just that one tunnel. :)

Comment: `x.x.x.x/xx dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src x.x.x.x.x
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1003 
default via x.x.x.x dev eth0`

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a "new" ping command (a bash script for example):

(rename your actual ping command to ping.back)

## mv /bin/ping /bin/ping.back

(edit a new "ping" command with vim/nano/whatever)

## vim /bin/ping

(put this inside the file and save it)

#! /bin/bash

/bin/ping.back -I eth0 $*

(now, give rwx-r-x-r-x to the file)

## chmod 755 /bin/ping

Play!

Comment: This does not work. And i try just to use the `/bin/ping -I eth0 -s <packetsize> <ip address>` and again no reply. But if i just ping like `ping -I eth0 -s 2334 <ipaddress>` ill get reply. This is strange :). How can bashrc get the arguments for root and all others not? And with root if i use /bin/ping with arguments to give me no reply ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a command alias in `/etc/bashrc` (*or maybe `/etc/profile.d`*)

```
alias ping='ping -I eth0'
```

Comment: Nop not working. The command that monit use is `COMMAND=/bin/ping 192.168.1.1` so when i ping like `/bin/ping 192.168.1.1` does not reply. There is no parameters in action. If i use ping ( now when i add the alias ) it reply. But monit saying thet ICMP failed. And in monit configuration i have the following `check host testhost with address 192.168.1.1
if failed icmp type echo count 3 with timeout 3 seconds then exec /tmp/restart.sh`

Comment: Tell monit not to use `/bin/ping`. Or maybe fix the routing in the environment.

Comment: How to tell the monit not to use /bin/ping ?

Comment: Show your Monit config file.

Comment: I have edit the question with the monit.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

You could mark the ICMP packets with iptables and force the output interface with iproute2. It's not as simple as Abdón's solution, but it should work.

Cya!